# Excel Formula Help: Lookup/Match string field from one table against another

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, formula, lookup-tables

Would appreciate any help with the following: I have a table that has a list of keywords, for example:

**Table 1:**

| Keywords |
| --- |
| Red |
| Blue |
| Orange |
| Green |

I need to scrub a string field in another table, **table 2**, against the strings in **table 1**:

So if **table 2** has the following string in cell B2 for example:

| Subject |
| --- |
| I like the color Blue |

Then I would need a formula in cell C2 that would indicate if the string contains any of the key words from **table 1**. In this case, since Blue is included in **table 1** then the there would be a match.

Please let me know if the above wasn't explained clearly enough, and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `SEARCH`.

For example, `=IF(SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH($D$2:$D$5, F3),0))>0,TRUE, FALSE)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ehi, try this

[image: See this]

```
List in column A
Subject in B1

Formula in column C1
=arrayFormula(if(REGEXMATCH($B$1,A1:A100),A1:A100,""))
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will upvote this after I get the required 15 reputation points.